# New paragraph for every element of an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a stateful component which gets its data from a api call. I want to print a new paragraph for each item of that array. Right now it prints a new paragraph for each Item but that paragraph contains the whole array..

```
 function ContentFunction () {
  const [value, setValue] = useState([]) //init with empty array

  function sendText (data) {
    setValue([...value, data]) //Push new data into array
  }

  async function handleClick (event) {
    switch (event.target.id) {
      case 'createSalesOrder':
      {
        const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/', {
          buttonClicked: 'createSalesOrder'

        })

        sendText(res.data)
        break
      }

      default:
        console.log('click didnt work')
    }
  }

  return (
    <main>
      <div className='container'>
        <Form>
          <Form.Group>
            <Button variant='success' className='button' onClick={handleClick} id='createSalesOrder'>Create Sales Order</Button>
          </Form.Group>
        </Form>
  {/* Here I want to create a new Paragraph for every Entry of the Array
        {value.map(item => <p key={value}>{value}</p>)} //render value array
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

Comment: In addition to the fix to the map function, what type is `res.data`? If it's an Array, you may be updating your state incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there

```
                                    //change this from `value` to `item`
 {value.map(item => <p key={value}>{item}</p>)}
```

In a map the first argument (in your case `item`) is the element at the current iteration.

You can also pass a second argument that will be the index which you can use for your key like this

```
 {value.map((item,index) => <p key={index}>{item}</p>)}
```

(Note the added `()` around the arguments `item,index`)

Answer (score 0):

You're close, just call the item variable in map instead:

```
  {value.map(item => <p key={value}>{item}</p>)} //render value array
```

Also, you want key to be unique, so consider changing to the index of the item in the array, like so:

```
{value.map((item, i) => <p key={i}>{item}</p>)} //render value array
```